# Form variable match with database table

Tags: php

I have a signup form in which email id and mobile number present. If any one enter email and phone number then it will match from database table **mobile and email**. If email or mobile matches then if condition otherwise else condition. I tried but its not working.

```
        if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
                            {

                                require"connection.php";
                                extract($_POST);

                                $result12=mysql_query("select mobile,email from mainaccount") or die (mysql_error());
                                while($row12=mysql_fetch_array($result12))
                            {

                                if($username==$row12["mobile"] || $email==$row12["email"])
                                {
                                echo"<b>Your Mobile number OR Email exists. Please use another Mobile number or Email!!!</b>";
                                die();
                                }

                                }

             <form method="post" id="loginForm" name="loginForm" action="" onsubmit="return executeOnSubmit();">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                    Mobile No.&nbsp;<span style="color:red">*</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" value="" name="username"  id="username" required  />
                    <div id="status"></div>
                    </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    Email.&nbsp;<span style="color:red">*</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" value="" name="email"  id="email" required  />
                    <div id="status"></div>
                    </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12-pull-right">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Register" name="submit"   />
                    <span style="margin-left:330px;"><b style="color:red">*</b> Means compulsary fields.</span>
                    </div>

                    </form>
```

Comment: I dont see "WHERE" condition in sql query

Comment: Tell me something first. Are both mobile no and email mandatory fields?

Comment: yes. mobile number and email are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use this entry if you want to check if there is such a user. You need to add to the query **"SELECT mobile,email from mainaccount WHERE mobile = $mobile OR email = $username"** condition and check the PHP side and the table is not empty or add a condition to the **"SELECT COUNT(*) as count from mainaccount WHERE mobile = $mobile OR email = $username"** and check the return value from the database is greater than 0. However, if you want to retrieve all the records and check for side php whether you there is you have to use a loop and subsequently compare the values and stop loops if the comparison returns true and you do next interesting things.

Comment: OK. Thanks, I understood.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to fetch all records from database. Try this =

```
    $result12 = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) from mainaccount where email = '$email' or mobile = '$mobile'");
        $row12 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result12);
        if($row12['count(*)']>0)
            {
                echo"<b>Your Mobile number OR Email exists. Please use another Mobile number or Email!!!</b>";
                die();
            }
```